# Javascript not setting this to value with apply or call

Tags: javascript, function, call, apply, global

Edit: the code below was made up on the spot to show how I was going about what I was doing. It definietely won't run, it is missing a lot of things.
Here is a working example in codepen: https://codepen.io/goducks/pen/XvgpYW

much shorter example: https://codepen.io/goducks/pen/ymXMyB

When creating a function that is using call or apply, the this value stays null when using getPerson. however, when I use apply or call with getPerson it returns the correct person.

Please critique, I am really starting to learn more and more. I am in the middle of a project section so it might be hard to change all the code, but my next project could implement this better.

call and apply are setting to the window and not the object.
I will provide code that is much simpler with the same concept of what I am talking about.

```
function createPerson(){
    this.manager = null;
    this.teamManager = null;
    this.setTeamManager = function(val){
        this.teamManager = val;
    }
    this.setManager = function(val){
        console.log('setting manager to',val);
        this.teamManager = val;
    }
    this.getTeamManager = function(){
        console.log('setting team manager to',val);
        return this.teamManager ;
    }
    this.getManager = function(){
        return this.manager;
    }
    this.appendSelect = function(elem){
        var that = this;
        createOtherSelects(that,elem);
    }
    //some functions that create selects with managers etc
    //now assume there are other selects that will filter down the teams,
    //so we might have a function that creates on change events
    function createOtherSelects(that){
        //code that creates locations, depending on location chosen will 
        //filter the managers
        $('#location').on('change',function(){
             //do some stuff
             //... then call create management
             createManagement(that,elem);
        });
    }
    function createManagement(that,elem){
         var currentLocation = that.location; //works
         var area = that.area;//works ... assume these are set above
         //code that returns a filter and unique set of managers back
         that.teamManager = [...new Set(
             data.map(person=>{
                 if(person.area==area && 
                    person.currentLocation==currentLocation
                 ){
                      return person;
                  }
              })
         )].filter(d=>{if(d){return d}});
         if(elem.length>0){
             var selectNames = ['selectManager','selectTeamManager'];
             var fcns = [that.setManager,that.setTeamManager];
             for(var i = 0; i < selectNames.length;i++){
                  //do stuff 
                  if(certainCriteriaMet){
                    // filter items

                      if(filteredManager == 1){
                           fcns[i].call(null,currentManager);//
                      }
                  }
             }    
        }
    }
}
var xx = new createPerson()
```

In console I see setting manager and setting team manager to with the correct values.

however when I call xx in console, I see everything else set except for 
xx.teamManager and xx.manager

instead it is applying to the window, so if I type teamManager in the console, it will return with the correct person.

If I straight up say 
`that.setManager('Steve')` 
or even  it works just fine.

```
xx.setManager('steve')
```

the this value in setManager is somehow changing from the current instance of the object to this window. I don't know why, and I would like to learn how to use apply and call using that for future reference.

Comment: I can't seem to replicate your issues in jsfiddle. Could you make a working example in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: I will try now. Thanks... how do you do console.log in jsfiddle?

Comment: You can use console.log same way you usually do, you'll see the output in your devtools

Comment: Added codepen link. Created a quick example.. run down, if you choose region, it will filter other area select to available areas within region, a new set of selects will appear with manager and team manager selects, those get filtered based off  the locations. While it is creating and filtering these managers, it can't set the manager or teamManager. You can see my comments in the createManagement function.

Comment: Please create a minimal example to reproduce. Do not have time to go over your huge file.

Comment: added a much shorter example to main post, but here it is https://codepen.io/goducks/pen/ymXMyB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with your following code

```
fcns[i].call(null,currentManager)
```

If you are not supplying "this" to call, it will be replaced with global object in non-strict mode.

```
fcns[i].call(that,currentManager)
```

See mdn article [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was wondering what the null aspect was from, it didn't occur to me that it is being passed specificity to location. Thanks again, it worked with no issue first time!

Answer (score 0):

From your codepen example, you need to change that line

```
fcnset[0].apply(that,[randomName]);
```

The first argument of the `apply` method is the context, if you are not giving it the context of your method it's using the global context be default. That's why you end up mutating the `window` object, and not the one you want !